# I cant get the array output to display in the table cell. How do I do it?

Tags: arrays

My html code is supposed to receive a list of inputed items and their numbers, then display the array, and then display it sorted in descending order of the numbers. But I can even get my code to output the array to the table cell. I can get it to output the array normally but I want to keep my full page styling, and just have the arrays output the specific table cell I want.

```
<html>
<head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css_styling.css" /></head>

<body onload="start()"><div id="container">
 <div id="wrapBanner"><div id="banner">
<img src="banner.png" alt="banner" />
 </div></div>

<div>   
<table border="1">
 <tr><th class="title" colspan="2">Unsorted List</th></tr>
 <tr><td class="subhead">Item</td><td>Quantity</td></tr>
 <tr><td class="subhead">
     <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      var arr_size = 5;
              function start ( )
      {
        var a1 = new Array(arr_size);
        var a2 = new Array( );
                for (var i=0; i<arr_size; i++)
        {
         a1[i] = prompt ("Enter the Item Name");
         a2[i] = prompt("Enter Item Number");
        }
         outputArray("Array two contains", a1);
         outputArray("Array two contains", a2);
       }
        function outputArray (header, the_array)
        {
          document.write("<h2>"+header+"</h2>"+"<br />");
                  document.write("<table border=\"1\"><thead><th align=\"left\">");
          document.write("Index</th></thead>");
                  document.write("<tbody>");

        for (var i=0; i<arr_size;i++){
        document.write("<tr><td>" + the_array[i] + "</td></tr>");
        document.write("</tbody></table>");
          }
</script>
</td>
  </tr>

</table>
</div>
</div></body>
</html>
</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 0):

The closing tags for `tbody` and `table` should be outside the for-loop. `document.write("</tbody></table>")` should not be inside the loop.